# Dereferncing NULL pointer to member function of class

Tags: c++

I am just curious that how is this program able to print the statement of func() of class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class foo
{
    public:
        void func ()
        {
            cout << "In func" << endl;
        }
    private:
        int a;
};

int main () {
    foo *f1 = NULL;
    f1->func();
}
```

Compiler version:
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.7-1ubuntu2) 4.4.7
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

How is that I am able to get the print of method func()?

Comment: You need to either create an instance of Foo, or make the function static.
    e.g. http://cpp.sh/4dyt

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing a null pointer yields Undefined Behaviour.

I can guess why this still works for you (but again it's UB!), but if you try to access a member variable in `func()` I'm pretty sure it will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer  means that you have undefined behavior.

However in this case on most implementations you will end up in correct function with `this` being `NULL`, the normal implementation of calling a non-virtual method is to set the hidden parameter `this` as being the pointer to the object (in this case `NULL`) and then just call the function. If you don't access member variables or call virtual methods you should be fine in most implementations.

Since you can't access members or call virtual functions or in any other way do anything useful with `this` pointer you're pretty close to the scenario of a `static` method and I'll suggest one use that instead if the `this` pointer is not used.

For the corner case where you want to be able to do nothing else with the `this` pointer than check for `NULL`ness you could still use a `static` method and explicitely pass the pointer to the object:

```
  static void func(foo* diz) {
       cout << "In func" << endl;

       if( diz != NULL ) {
           diz->actual_work_on_diz();
       }
  }
```

Comment: local variables probably should be "member variables"

Comment: @DavidHaim Yes of course, I'll change that.